# CMD does not append WSL output

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux, redirection, wsl2, append

In cmd.exe, I try to append WSL2 output to some file, like this:

```
C:\somepath>echo Some contents> somefile

C:\somepath>bash.exe --noprofile --norc -c "echo APPEND">> somefile
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.


C:\somepath>type somefile
APPEND
ntents

C:\somepath>
```

As you can see, somehow the output is not *appended* to the file but *overwrites the start* of the file. I cannot imagine this is by design somehow.

It only happens with WSL or Bash, not with regular commands of course. But I would expect cmd to be responsible for writing to the correct place. What is so special about WSL output?

The "Processing fstab with mount -a failed." is a line I see with every WSL invocation. I don't think it's related...?

Answer (score 0):

The boundaries between Windows and WSL/Linux are not well-defined,
so sometimes there would be strange side-effects.

In your case, probably `bash` didn't know that `somefile` had some data
already in it, so it just overwrote the beginning of the file's contents.

You could formulate the command differently, so as to avoid crossing too
many boundaries :

```
bash.exe --noprofile --norc -c "echo APPEND >> somefile"
```

Comment: Your problem with "Processing fstab with mount -a failed" might be because you have installed several distributions with the wrong one set as default. See also [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9250).

Comment: Moving the `>>` into bash would require translating file paths :-(
And all I have is `Ubuntu (Default)`.

Comment: It worked for me without file translation.